# How to cross platform copy a file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, copy, cross-platform

Basically I need to copy a file (FAT or NTFS either works) without using the Microsoft `System.IO.File.Copy` Libraries. I am working with COSMOS (C# open source managed operating system) and since that is not Windows, the `File.Copy` does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that there are COSMOS routines for this sort of IO.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any other part of the System.IO namespace? Most notably, the various Streams?

If not, then I fail to see how you should be able to copy anything.

But, assuming you can open files for reading and writing, you can implement your own copy method trivially:

```
private void CopyFile(string source, string dest)
{
    using (var input = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var output = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = input.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
                output.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
    }
}
```

(Above code not tested)

Comment: [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx)

Comment: That one is new since .net 4 I think, chances are COSMOS doesn't have it. But if it's there, then by all means the OP should use it instead of reimplementing it

Comment: It is not related with `COSMOS`. It is an alternative for your loop

Comment: Sadly that doesnt work. Since COSMOS doesnt support this, you would have to write your own FS drivers, HDD drivers, the whole shabang. Oh Well...Goodbye COSMOS